"Best" energy efficiency via capacity of uncoded BPSK AWGN
I have numerically approximated the capacity of an uncoded, binary uniform input, real AWGN BPSK channel versus the SNR using mutual information and entropy, via Gauss-hermite quadrature. My task is to examine the capacity plotted versus $\frac{E_b}{N_0}$, and answer three questions.

"What do you notice?" I guess that means that the curve saturates at the limits, and therefore there is no achievable information rate greater than one, and at a certain SNR, there is no benefit to further increasing signal power.
Whether information can be transmitted "arbitrarily efficiently", which I assume means with arbitrarily low $\frac{E_b}{N_0}$. It seems obvious that no, one can't, because I can see that the capacity tends to zero for $\frac{E_b}{N_0} \rightarrow 0$.
How one can achieve "best" energy efficiency.

The third question especially confuses me. Wouldn't this actually be a "soft" trade-off between power consumption and capacity? What would be a good target value for the capacity then? Or is there actually a way to determine an optimal $\frac{E_b}{N_0}$ value?
I am quite new to wireless comms, so apologies if this may appear trivial.
The plot in question:


Hello. What do you mean by "arbitrarily low error probability greater than one" as probability is lower than or equal to 1 by usual definitions? For other questions, first define "best energy efficiency". Maybe I don't understand what you want to do. If I were you, I would use the classic energy efficiency reasoning : first fix the rate $R$ I want to transmit, next choose the lowest $Eb/N0$ that the channel capacity $C(Eb/N0)=R$, then the power derived from such $Eb/N0$ is the efficient scheme.

Such scheme can be achieved theoretically by random coding, can be approached practically by codes like turbocodes, LDPC, and polar codes.

"arbitrarily low error probability greater than one" is a typo as I wrote the question a bit late at night. I edited it to fix the mistake.
"first define "best energy efficiency"": This is the term my university instructors used in the task. I don't know what they mean either and couldn't find any clear definition online.
